# I cannot find the xpath for the radio button which should be random using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, random

I cannot find the XPath or the class name for the radio button which should select color randomly from the list using selenium in a google form(link). Other name, age, country, and email are working fine with the XPath. I want the code to select any of the four colors randomly and automatically, I don't want it to wait for me to select a color. Every time getting an error comes up. Can anyone help me?
Code is -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from faker import Faker
import random
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://forms.gle/PL3W5TxZVVJHRa1W9")
faker = Faker()

colors = ["green", "blue", "black", "red"]


for i in range(20):
    name = faker.name()
    age = random.randint(18, 99)
    country = faker.country()
    email = faker.email()
    color = random.choice(colors)
    name_field = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
    name_field.send_keys(name)
    age_field = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
    age_field.send_keys(str(age))
    country_field = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
    country_field.send_keys(country)
    email_field = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
    email_field.send_keys(email)
    color_field = driver.find_element("class name",'//div[@class="mG61Hd"]')
    color_field.send_keys(color)


    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[type='submit']")
    submit_button.click()


driver.quit()
```

Comment: could you add the error to the question?

Comment: 'nosuchelementexception' error i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the 4 elements choosing the color having the same locator `//div[contains(@data-params,'color')]//label`. So, you can choose one of them randomly.
The following code works:

```py
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc5v43tKVcCl_a-kRW8jijoUuK-O4hR2CYNK-CDMRe8NulXog/viewform"
driver.get(url)
color_index = random.randint(1, 4)
random_color_locator = "(//div[contains(@data-params,'color')]//label)[{}]".format(color_index)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, random_color_locator))).click()
```

Comment: I want the code to select any of the four colors randomly and automatically, I don't want it to wait for me to select a color.

Comment: My code does exactly what you want. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I tried I am getting "TimeoutException: Message: Stacktrace:Backtrace:(No symbol)...." error.

Comment: That's strange. I run this code several times and it worked for me 100%

Comment: Have you maximized the screen with `options.add_argument("start-maximized")` or similar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251372/discussion-between-rishav-pandit-and-prophet).

Answer (score 2):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element associated with any of the random color from the list and substituting using [***f-strings***](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/), you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc5v43tKVcCl_a-kRW8jijoUuK-O4hR2CYNK-CDMRe8NulXog/viewform")
  # WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='green']"))).click()
  colors = ["green", "blue", "black", "red"]
  color = random.choice(colors)
  print(color)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//span[text()='{color}']"))).click()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  green
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: green]

Comment: I want the code to select any of the four colors randomly and automatically, I don't want it to wait for me to select a color.

Comment: @RishavPandit Checkout the updated answer. See [Formatting in Python](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/f-string-formatting-in-python)